# Cloning a Bootable SD Card from Linux Using dd command

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi with the default, store-bought operating systems on it. I want to wipe the SD card clean so that I can put in a new operating system, but I want to preserve the original OS in a backup disc image. I planned to store it in a .bin file. The SD card has two partitions.

I used the following command to figure out which drive is the SD card.

```
sudo dmesg | tail
```

--output--

```
[ 2954.642182] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk _
[ 2955.149750] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

I believe this tells me that it is under dev/sdb2, but I also tried dev/sdb, ~/dev/sdb and ~/dev/sdb2. I used the following command to create the image:

```
dd if="dev/sdb2" of="~/Desktop/Pi Backup/Pi.bin"
```

But when I try to do this it returns the error message

```
dd: opening `dev/sdb2': No such file or directory
```

I'm running Linux Mint, Cinnamon.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try /dev/sdb2. Using Sudo? Did you manage to do the first partition too? 
Also ~ infront of anything refers to /home/*user*/

Comment: i guess the mainproblem is your typo: `dev/sdb2` will be relative to your current working directory and most likely not existing, whereas `/dev/sdb2` should exist in the root-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All devices are under /dev

dev is looking for dev under the current directory and ~/dev is looking for dev under your home directory.

/dev/sdb2 if the second partition, I would expect use have /dev/sdb1 (the first partition) too.

sudo dmesg | tail -30

will give you the last 30 lines, then you should be able to see the sdb1 too.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to actually make a backup of `/dev/sdb` if the objective is to clone the card?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing:

```
sudo dd if="/dev/mmcblk0p1" of="Pi_1.bin"
sudo dd if="/dev/mmcblk0p2" of="Pi_2.bin"
```

try:

```
sudo dd if="/dev/mmcblk0" of="Pi.bin"
```

`p1` and `p2` are the partitions in that device and you want to make an image of the entire device.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Mint 14 and I did `mount` and the SDcard shows as 2 partitions like below

`/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /media/nig/3312-932F type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)`

`/dev/mmcblk0p2 on /media/nig/b7b5ddff-ddb4-48dd-84d2-dd47bf00564a type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)`

so I then did

`sudo dd if="/dev/mmcblk0p1" of="Pi_1.bin"`

`sudo dd if="/dev/mmcblk0p2" of="Pi_2.bin"`

seemed to work, not sure about restoring, not tried that yet